# Wireguard peer rejecting traffic

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, wireguard, openbsd

My Wireguard setup randomly stopped working yesterday and I don't know how to trace the source of the problem.
I inspected the traffic with Wireshark and it shows that the traffic gets sent from the local peer to the server, but never gets back.
SSH and Ping still work while the VPN is active, but everything else gets rejected.
I have the configurations attached in the links below:

Server config:
https://0x0.st/HLrm.txt

Client config:
https://0x0.st/HLra.txt

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: can you show (in the question, not as an external link) the **actual** configs (clearly with keys removed) rather than the output of wg